# Remove leading spaces, carriage returns and unwanted tags using regexp

Tags: javascript, html, regex, trim, removing-whitespace

I am currently using `CKEditor` for user to write document.
Normally few users tend to start with a few whitespaces and two new lines and then actual content. Say example html would look something like this:
Different Inputs:

- `\n\n  <p>&nbsp; </p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>This is a simple document</p>`
- `<p></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>Testing data</p>`
- `<p></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>This is my plan</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p><b> Hi Hello</b>`

I need to get rid of all unwanted "leading" tags, spaces and carriage returns only.
Output should be as follows:

- `<p>This is a simple document</p>`
- `<p>Testing data</p>`
- `<p>This is my plan</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p><b> Hi Hello</b>`

I tried using trim() function in javascript but it just removed leading whitespaces. I was not able to remove tags. Is there anyway this can be achieved in javascript using a RegExp?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Regexes will not help you. They will only give you more problems. sgml does not lend itself well to regular expressions. What you should use instead is a dom parser, walk the dom tree and clean out nodes that only contain white spaces. Incidentally you already have such a dom parser in your browser, so you can use that to your advantage. Put that content in an iframe (just to guard against unbalanced formatting), then walk the dom and delete anything with only white space content. Then serialize back to a string again

Comment: Shouldn't last line be `<p>This is my plan</p><b> Hi Hello</b>`?

Comment: I just want leading whitespaces and unwanted tags to be removed not trailing/middle ones

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you are only going to have `p` tags with no attributes as in your examples, then the following should work:

```js
var strs = [
    "\n\n  <p>&nbsp; </p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>This is a simple document</p>",
    "<p></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>Testing data</p>",
    "<p></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>This is my plan</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p><b> Hi Hello</b>"
];

var re = /^((&nbsp;)|\s|(\<p\>(&nbsp;|\s)*\<\/p\>))+/i;

for(var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
    console.log('------------');
    console.log(i, strs[i].replace(re, ''));
}
```